# How can I export Freedcamp data(To do's etc) to a file?

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to export my Freedcamp data to a file like an Excel spreadsheet. So far what I have come across is the following code:

```
$('#todo-group-177701 .td_content').each(function() 
{console.log($(this).find('.td_description').text() + '| ' + $(this).find('.tag[data-
type=assigned-to]').text() + '| ' + $(this).find('.tag[data-type=progress]').text())})
```

I've tried running it on Google Chrome console, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

We will be releasing backups that do just that in the next two weeks.